# Laravel get date from database return a string

Tags: laravel, date, php-carbon

I'm trying to get the date from a timestamp field in my database, i'm using a timestamp because with date Carbon doesn't add the hours/minutes/seconds in my date, and I need them.

When I try to get the date it works but return a string, and I can't use the Carbon methods with this string, what can I do ? I don't know why it's a string.

Here is what I try to do :

```
@foreach($disponibilites as $comp)
       <span class="badge badge-pill indigo">{{ $comp->date_debut->diffForHuman() }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Are you sure? `Carbon::now()->toDateString()` produces a full datetime string (2018-06-23 10:30:18), and there are billions of formats to choose from, and `Carbon::now()->addHours(2)` or whatever will do just what you suggest it doesn't

Comment: I found my solution, i do this : {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($comp->date_debut)->addHour(2)->diffForHumans() }}

Answer (score 1):

add the column name in date attribute in model as the following :

```
 protected $dates = ['date_debut'];
```